# Jade/Pug não repetir o mesmo código

Tags: html, template, jade, pug

Gostaria de saber como fazer para não precisar repetir códigos, não sei se usando o `for`, por exemplo tenho esse código abaixo que corresponde a um card com dados de um educador vou ter varios desses onde so mudarei os dados mas a estrutura do código é a mesma, vou precisar criar um slide com esses cards, na tela vai poder aparecer de 4 em 4, gostaria de aprender algum recurso do jade/pug onde eu deixo o código mais limpo sem precisar ficar repetindo ele.

```html
  //- CARD 4
  div.card-educator.item
   ul.educator
    li.educator-photo
     figure
      img(src="img/eunice.png", alt="Eunice Magalhães Fonseca")
      figcaption Eunice Magalhães Fonseca
    li.hr
     hr
    li.icons.icon-boy-girl
     svg
      use(xlink:href='svg/myicons.svg#boy-girl')
     span 252 alunos
    li.icons.icon-gamepad
     svg
      use(xlink:href='svg/myicons.svg#gamepad')
     span 252 alunos
    li.icons.icon-question-list
     svg
      use(xlink:href='svg/myicons.svg#question-list')
     span 252 alunos
    li.button
     button(type='button') Selecionar
```

Answer (score 0):

Utilize o recurso mixin.

```
mixin loop-lista(photourl,nome,svg-bg-url,totalbg,svg-gamepad-url,totalgp,svg-ql,totalql)
    li.educator-photo
       figure
           img(src=photourl, alt=nome)
            figcaption 
                =nome
            li.hr hr
            li.icons.icon-boy-girl
                svg
                    use(xlink:href=svg-bg-url)
                span =totalbg
            li.icons.icon-gamepad
                svg
                    use(xlink:href=svg-gamepad-url)
                span totalgp
            li.icons.icon-question-list
                svg
                    use(xlink:href=svg-ql)
                span totalql
            li.button
                button(type='button') Selecionar
```

Para chamar na pagina principal

```
+loop-lista("img/eunice.png","Eunice Magalhães Fonseca","svg/myicons.svg#boy-girl","250 Alunos","svg/myicons.svg#gamepad","210 Alunos","svg/myicons.svg#question-list","200 Alunos")
+loop-lista("img/maria.png","Maria José Fonseca","svg/myicons.svg#boy-girl","250 Alunos","svg/myicons.svg#gamepad","210 Alunos","svg/myicons.svg#question-list","200 Alunos")
```

Se *svg/x.svg* forem recursos fixos, pode deixá-los dentro do mixin e remover dos parâmetros, ficando assim:

```
mixin loop-lista(photourl,nome,totalbg,totalgp,totalql)
    li.educator-photo
       figure
           img(src=photourl, alt=nome)
            figcaption 
                =nome
            li.hr hr
            li.icons.icon-boy-girl
                svg
                    use(xlink:href='svg/myicons.svg#boy-girl')
                span =totalbg
            li.icons.icon-gamepad
                svg
                    use(xlink:href='svg/myicons.svg#gamepad')
                span totalgp
            li.icons.icon-question-list
                svg
                    use(xlink:href='svg/myicons.svg#question-list')
                span totalql
            li.button
                button(type='button') Selecionar 

+loop-lista("img/eunice.png","Eunice Magalhães Fonseca","250 Alunos","210 Alunos","200 Alunos")
+loop-lista("img/maria.png","Maria José Fonseca","250 Alunos","210 Alunos","200 Alunos")
```